# Use Apache Airflow to do a simple select * and dump it to email

Tags: sql, airflow, presto

I am an [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) newb and I have a very simple requirement to query an existing table using a somewhat complex select query and then email it's result to myself.

Assuming that it's a basic sql query like:

```
select * from table where somevar="some_value"
```

and I just want this data to be sent as an email from Airflow - how to do this.

I've already started watching some youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43wHwwZhJMo&list=PLYizQ5FvN6pvIOcOd6dFZu3lQqc6zBGp2&index=4) - but it's already feeling like an overkill for my usecase.

Would appreciate a simple gist of doing the above.

Thanks

Comment: you can write a custom transfer operator: `SqlToEmailOperator`. In the Airflow source code you can find for example `SqlToSlackOperator` so most of the ground work is already there it just need to change the Slack part with sending email.

Answer (score 0):

First step is executing the query to get the result and store it somewhere (S3, GCS, ...). For the libs you can use, it depends on which database/processing tool you are using, for example if you want to query a postgres db, the operator `PostgresOperator` doesn't support storing result, so you need to use the hook `PostgresHook` in a new operator, to read the result and store it, same if you are using presto, you can use [PrestoHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-presto/stable/_api/airflow/providers/presto/hooks/presto/index.html#airflow.providers.presto.hooks.presto.PrestoHook).

For the email sending, you can create a new subclass from `EmailOperator`, which download the file from S3/GCS, and send it using `EmailOperator` to your email.

Why you cannot store the file locally instead of uploading and downloading it to object store service? That's because in some Airflow executors (k8s, celery), the tasks are executing in different workers, so the data downloaded in a worker are not available for the others, but you have a `LocalExecutor` you can download the file locally and use the `EmailOperator` to send it.